# c# MVC 4 send picture

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I would like my android aplication to get pictures from MVC WebAPI.
When I use code examples of sending a picture, I get only the header without the data:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
response.Content = new StreamContent(new FileStream(@"~\IMG_0763.jpg",Filemo,FileAccess.Read)); 
response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/png");
return response;
```

I browse the address and get:

```
StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Content-Type: image/png
}
```

How do I get the picture itself in the browser?
What happened here? was the picture sent and I dont see it or the picture was not send?
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: The picture was sent. Check `Content-Length` in the response to be sure. How do you process the response on the client-side?

Answer (score 1):

This is working for us:

```
var result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(requestFile.FileContent);
result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
            {
                FileName = requestFile.FileName
            };

return result;
```

Where FileContent is of type byte[].